# What to do with old GIS books/manuals/etc?

Tags: history

We're having an office clear-out and have come across a number of old GIS paper materials. Random examples (to give a taste - there are about 20-30 in all) include:

- Postcodes: The New Geography (Book - 1992)
- Intermap (Product Handbook and Quick Start Guide (2004))
- ARC Macro Language (Self-study Workbook 1993)
- Understanding GIS; The ARC/INFO Method (ESRI Book, 1990)
- Institute of British Geographers; Transactions New Series; Volume 16 Number 1 1991
- arc/info; Computer mapping and geographica information management system (Folder, probably training materials; Nov 1985!)

So I'm wondering - what should we do with them? Is there anywhere that would take "historic" GIS materials (museum, library etc)? They're all a bit too specialised for a regular charity shop but it seems a shame to just dump them.

(Note: I'm in the UK if that makes any difference)

Comment: Any Uni/College with the GIS courses - Kingston Uni, SW London will take them. Not sure if the AML book is much use to ArcGIS users anymore as Workstation is phased out at 10.1 but if history of GIS Programming is researched might be handy to someone. email library@kingston.ac.uk

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it refers to a particular point in time - presumably the books have now found a home even if it is a dump.

Comment: @PolyGeo - That doesn't make sense. Almost *every* single question on here relates to a specific period in time. What if someone has another suggested method? Others could gain from the answer.

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan I think it is a very small percentage of questions that pertain to such a specific point in time as this question.  They are asked at a particular point of time and then re-used by visitors over long periods.  If you want to generalize your question (which lists specific books being disposed of in 2012) so that it can be used to offer advice for any GIS books being disposed of at any point in time then feel free to do so.  That way it will go into the re-open queue.

Answer (score 4):

Generally i think you could throw away manuals for products more than five years old, unless they are really old of course. General books, demonstrating ideas, algorithms and procedures does not age that fast. Check if any college/university still has them on their curriculum?

Answer (score 0):

Local Geography department (college/university) might take them.

Dunno about the computer language books, those seem useless but the others might be of interest to them